# Voting to delete occasionally fails to post the vote to a valid URL

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-delete

Every now and then - and some days more often - I'll vote to delete a question only to be presented with an unhelpful error message:

[fail http://shog9.com/deleteretry.png](http://shog9.com/deleteretry.png)

Fortunately, retrying is easy - I need only click that little red error box, as instead of dismissing itself as promised it will immediately retry... and fail.

A quick check with Firebug reveals the cause for the error: the script is attempting to post to the following bogus URL:

> https://stackoverflow.com/posts//vote/10

Note the double-slash there in the middle - a post ID is supposed to go between those.

*Usually*, reloading the page will correct the problem. Sometimes, several reloads are necessary. Occasionally, blood sacrifice is required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just pushed out a change to how click handlers are being bound to UI elements.

If you still experience this, please view the page source and find the delete link for the post you're trying to delete, e.g.

```
<a id="delete-post-12345" class="" title="vote to remove this post">delete</a>
```

where 12345 is the post id.

If that post id is there, then we've got a javascript problem - will be helpful to know!